# Why is my nested CSS transition not working?

Tags: html, css, sass

I've got two classes, `fade-item` and `fade`. `fade` is nested in `fade-item` like this:

```
<a class="product-item fade-item" (mousemove)="hoverOn(i)" (mouseleave)="hoverOff(i) >
    <div class='fade' *ngIf='item.active' >
        <button class="botonete botonete--primary botonete--hero-one">
            Button Text
        </button>
    </div>
</a>
```

When I hover over `fade-item` with `mousemove`, a value is set on the item so it shows using `*ngIf='item.active'`, but it is supposed to do an opacity transition, which is not happening.

css code below:

```
.fade {
    opacity: 0;
    transition: opacity 1s ease-in-out;
    -moz-transition: opacity 1s ease-in-out;
    -webkit-transition: opacity 1s ease-in-out;
 }
     
 .fade-item:hover {
     .fade{
         opacity: 1;
     }
 }
```

Anyone knows what I am doing wrong?

Comment: Im sorry, I don't get what is wrong with that, would you mind explaining yourself a bit more? my logic is 'I set the `fade` properties ---> when I fade over `fade-items` ---> change `fade` opacity to 1
Or at least that was my logic for this kind of nesting.

Comment: Ahh.. the formatting is weird on your question. Your SASS is correct. I edited the question to align the brackets.

Comment: As other comments pointed out - are you compiling the SASS to CSS?

Comment: This styling code is contained in a `.scss` file, so I assume it compiles to sass. It's the first time I have to use this styling language so no error is discarded.

Comment: No, SCSS doesn't compile to SASS. SCSS *is* SASS with minor formatting differences. SCSS/SASS compiles to CSS which is what your browser reads. You need to have something that *watches* the `.scss` file (like `gulp` or your code editor) so when you save the file, it will compile to the CSS file. I'm guessing that's what the problem is here. You're not actually compiling to CSS.

Answer (score 0):

The code you wrote it's scss. If you are looking for a css answer it should be like this:

```
.fade {
  opacity: 0;
  transition: opacity 1s ease-in-out;
  -moz-transition: opacity 1s ease-in-out;
  -webkit-transition: opacity 1s ease-in-out;
}
     
.fade-item:hover .fade{
  opacity: 1;
}
```

Comment: Given that OP tagged their question with [tag:sass], I'm sure they're aware of that.

Comment: I can't seem to get the transition to work using this either. Im not quite sure about proper scss or css formating, since I inherited this proyect but I wasnt part of the original development team. You gave me something to investigate, thank you.

Answer (score 0):

When an element is dynamically added to the page, its styles are computed at that moment. For your transition to work, you would need it to have been already computed despite not actually existing yet.

Minimal example of it *not* working:

```js
const elem = document.getElementById('hoverme');
elem.addEventListener('pointerover',e=>{
  elem.insertAdjacentHTML('beforeend','<span id="fade">Dynamically added!</span>');
});
elem.addEventListener('pointerout',e=>{
  elem.children[0].remove();
});
```

```css
#fade {
  opacity: 0;
  transition: opacity 1s;
}
#hoverme:hover #fade {
  opacity: 1;
}
```

```html
<div id="hoverme">Hover me!</div>
```

Instead, you need to give it an `animation` that will begin when the element is added to the document.

Example:

```js
const elem = document.getElementById('hoverme');
elem.addEventListener('pointerover',e=>{
  elem.insertAdjacentHTML('beforeend','<span id="fade">Dynamically added!</span>');
});
elem.addEventListener('pointerout',e=>{
  elem.children[0].remove();
});
```

```css
#fade {
  animation: fade-in 1s both;
}
@keyframes fade-in {
  from {opacity:0}
  to {opacity:1}
}
```

```html
<div id="hoverme">Hover me!</div>
```

Comment: Thank you very much! I did not know that, and im quite sure this is what Im looking for. Thanks.